# Openpyxl: How to add filters to all columns

Tags: python, openpyxl

I can open a worksheet, how do I add the little filter menus to all columns without turning on any filters?

I can do it in xlsxwriter with

```
worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, 0, num_of_col)
```

How do I do it in openpyxl?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can simply read `ws.dimensions` and it will return a string value with your range from "A1:XX". I used this to apply filters to my entire excel  spreadsheet.

```
import openpyxl as px

wb= px.load_workbook('Data/Test01.xlsx')
ws = wb.active

ws.auto_filter.ref = ws.dimensions

wb.save('Data/Test03.xlsx')
```

Answer (score 10):

All you need to do is to set `worksheet.auto_filter.ref` to the full range of worksheet cells.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook('Data/Test01.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook['Sheet1']

FullRange = "A1:" + get_column_letter(worksheet.max_column) \
+ str(worksheet.max_row)
worksheet.auto_filter.ref = FullRange

workbook.save('Data/Test03.xlsx')
```