# How to Autofilter excel-sheet before outputting

Tags: python, pandas

I am making  function for a script that fetches data from an api which will output a dataframe to an excel-sheet. I need autofiltering(as an optional argument).

I am almost done, but keep getting an Attribute error with following explanation **'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'autofilter'**

This is the code i have been trying

```
def generate_xls(df, file_name, sheet_name, column_names=None, auto_filter=True):

    if column_names != None:
        df.columns = column_names

    print("appending the data in order...")   

    print("\nCreating excel-file")

    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_name + '.xls')    

    df.to_excel(writer,sheet_name,index=False)

    if auto_filter == True:
        for worksheet in writer.sheets.values():  
            worksheet.autofilter(df.columns)            

    writer.save()
    print("Excel-file generated.")
```

It works fine without the autofiltering, but it really is important for me to have it, as there are others that might need it. Any advice would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the input. I solved the problem using pandas and xlsxwriter engine, in a writer object:

```
    if auto_filter == True:
        for worksheet in writer.sheets.values():
            row_count = len(df.index)
            column_count = len(df.columns)
            worksheet.autofilter(0, 0, row_count-1, column_count-1)                                
    writer.save()
    print("Excel-file generated.")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you first need to add the auto filter, assuming you're using [OpenPyXl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/filters.html):

> To add a filter you define a range and then add columns and sort conditions
>
> ````
> ws.auto_filter.ref = "A1:B15"
> ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(0, ["Kiwi", "Apple", "Mango"])
> ws.auto_filter.add_sort_condition("B2:B15") ```
> ````

Of course you can omit the `add_filter` and `add_sort_conditions`, and leave that to the user to configure. [You will need to do simply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51566349/openpyxl-how-to-add-filters-to-all-columns):

```
worksheet.auto_filter.ref = worksheet.dimensions
```