# openpyxl table change table existing (automatic) filter

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When a table is created, Excel automatically creates filters for all columns.

Then in my Python + openpyxl code I'd like to filter out some data, but I cannot realise how to retrieve and change this existing filter.

Consider my table has possibly "Fail", "Pass", "Skipped" and blank values
and I just want to see "Fail" and "Pass".

If I try to add a filter to a table, it simply seems to be ignored:

```
ws.auto_filter.add_filter_column(1,
                                 ["Fail", "Pass"])
```

Later a bunch of data is added and table "ref" is updated accordingly.
Opening the file in Excel, though, shows all the filter values selected - no filtering at all.

Any clues?
Thanks!

---

**UPDATE:**

I noticed that the table object has its own `autoFilter` field so I thought it would be fair if I create an `AutoFilter` and set it up accordingly.
It looked like it would succeed but when saving my file this filters got lost.

Digging down I saw that `openpyxl/worksheet/_writer.py` at `write_tables(self)` was calling `table._initialise_columns()` and it screwed up my filters.

OK, so I needed to initialise my `table.tableColumns` attribute as well and what started as a simple task became a lot of boiler plate hidden in functions `initialise_columns()` and `initialise_filters()`.

```
    table = Table(displayName=table_name,
                  ref=ref_range,
                  tableColumns=initialise_columns(),
                  autoFilter=initialise_filters(),
                  **kwargs)
    ws.add_table(table)
```

After changing table data now I have to update two references:

```
    table .ref = ref
    table .autoFilter.ref = ref
```

Well, then it "almost" works...
I can open the file with Excel with no errors, filter appears, I have filter values selected as expected but data does not get filtered.

If I click on filter values (even if the selected items are the same after this) then Excel applies the filter and results are as expected.

Comment: Relevant [Autofilter excel-sheet before outputting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100768/7414759)

Comment: I add my filter but later change the data on table (and update table `.ref`. I was not touching `auto_filter.ref`. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

> I noticed that the table object has its own autoFilter field so I thought it would be fair if I create an AutoFilter and set it up accordingly. It looked like it would succeed but when saving my file this filters got lost.

> Digging down I saw that openpyxl/worksheet/_writer.py at write_tables(self) was calling table._initialise_columns() and it screwed up my filters.

I found a very **simple solution (workaround) for the bug** without any extra (duplicated) code. Yes I will call it a bug! This bug makes the constructor parameter autofilter of a Table useless.

The AutoFilter of a table is set/replaced to the default AutoFilter only at the first time you save the workbook. Afterwards the auto filter property is untouched by openpyxl.

```
workbook.save('table.xlsx')  # 1st time 

table.autoFilter = AutoFilter(ref=table.ref)
table.autoFilter.add_filter_column(0, ['Bananas'])
table.autoFilter.add_sort_condition("B2:B15")

workbook.save('table.xlsx')  # 2nd time
```

**so far, so good....**

> Well, then it "almost" works... I can open the file with Excel with no errors, filter appears, I have filter values selected as expected but data does not get filtered.
> I have the same problem. I tested it with table and normal worksheet. In both cases the same behavior.

**Is this a bug, or a feature?**

I had a look into the openpyxl bug tracker :-(

https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/issues/1156

The problem with overwritten AutoFilter (with a simple solution) is known for over two years :-(