# How to disable autofilter in openpyxl tables?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When I create a table using openpyxl, it adds an auto filter by default on all columns. The behavior is reproducible using the example provided in the [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/worksheet_tables.html). I would like to display the tables without the auto filter.

This behavior is controlled by the `autoFilter` parameter in the class `openpyxl.worksheet.table.Table`. I have tried setting it to `None`, as well as different values for the `filterColumn` parameter in the class `openpyxl.worksheet.filters.AutoFilter` however, nothing seems to work.

Has anyone been able to disable the auto filter?

Comment: Hi, I am also looking for this exact thing. Have you found a solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick for me:

> ws2.auto_filter.add_sort_condition(None)

ws2 is the name of of my worksheet, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

refer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66377091

```
workbook.save('table.xlsx')  # 1st time

table.autoFilter = None    

workbook.save('table.xlsx')  # 2nd time
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, `TableColumn`s are created at the time of xlsx writing ([_initialise_columns()](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/c95449fa6295debe169f265c09182d6d7bd68a33/openpyxl/worksheet/_writer.py#L268)).

The documentation mentions that [you can call this private method](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/3.1/worksheet_tables.html#:%7E:text=Or%20initialise%20the%20column%20headings%20manually%3A) to initialize on your.

However, the docs don't mention how to use the `AutoFilter` attribute of the `Table`.

From inspection of a loaded excel file with the filters turned off, I modified [the code used to prep the table](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/c95449fa6295debe169f265c09182d6d7bd68a33/openpyxl/worksheet/_writer.py#L267-277) in `WorksheetWriter.write_tables` to create a function that manually turns off filters in my table.

```py
from warnings import warn
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.utils import range_boundaries
from openpyxl.worksheet.cell_range import CellRange
from openpyxl.worksheet.filters import AutoFilter, FilterColumn
from openpyxl.worksheet.table import Table, TableColumn, TableStyleInfo
from openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet import Worksheet


def remove_table_filters(table: Table, ws: Worksheet) -> None:
    # Only remove filters if there is a header
    if not table.headerRowCount:
        return

    # Initialize table if not done (from WorksheetWriter.write_tables)
    if not table.tableColumns:
        min_col, min_row, max_col, max_row = range_boundaries(table.ref)
        for idx in range(min_col, max_col + 1):
            col = TableColumn(id=idx, name=f"Column{idx}")
            table.tableColumns.append(col)
        table.autoFilter = AutoFilter(ref=table.ref)
        try:
            row = ws[table.ref][0]
            for cell, col in zip(row, table.tableColumns):
                if cell.data_type != "s":
                    warn("File may not be readable: column headings must be strings.")
                col.name = str(cell.value)
        except TypeError:
            warn("Column headings are missing, file may not be readable")

    filter_columns = table.autoFilter.filterColumn
    # clear any current FilterColumns that might be there
    filter_columns.clear()
    for idx in range(len(table.tableColumns)):
        # ColId of filters is relative to Table, so starts at 0
        # Remove filter with hiddenButton=True
        filter_columns.append(FilterColumn(colId=idx, hiddenButton=True, filters=None))


wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
treeData = [
    ["", "", "", ""],
    ["", "", "", ""],
    ["", "Type", "Leaf Color", "Height"],
    ["", "Maple", "Red", 549],
    ["", "Oak", "Green", 783],
    ["", "Pine", "Green", 1204],
]
for row in treeData:
    ws.append(row)
c_range = CellRange(min_col=2, max_col=ws.max_column, min_row=3, max_row=ws.max_row)
table = Table(
    displayName="Table1",
    ref=c_range.coord,
    headerRowCount=1,
    tableStyleInfo=TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleMedium16", showRowStripes=True),
)
remove_table_filters(table, ws)

ws.add_table(table)

wb.save("test.xlsx")
```

This seemed to work for me. However, if you manually set the columns like this, [some relationships done by the xlsx writer](https://foss.heptapod.net/openpyxl/openpyxl/-/blob/c95449fa6295debe169f265c09182d6d7bd68a33/openpyxl/worksheet/_writer.py#L278-281) won't be created. I don't know enough about excel XML structure to know if this matters. I didn't see any issues with my files, but just a heads up in case you see odd behavior.