# How to turn off table filters in OpenPyXl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am using OpenPyXL to create a new table. When I do this, table filters are automatically created with it.

I would like to turn off the filters, and have tried the following, but been unsuccessful. How do I turn off table filters with OpenPyXL?

```
table_style = pyxl.worksheet.table.TableStyleInfo(name="TableStyleLight1",showRowStripes=True)
new_IO_Table = pyxl.worksheet.table.Table(displayName='IO_List', ref='A2:AO49',tableStyleInfo=table_style, autoFilter=None) 

#I thought setting AutoFilter=None would solve my issue, but it does not.

ws_IO_List.tables['IO_List'] = new_IO_Table
```

This code still causes my table to have filters:
[image]

Comment: As I understand it and the documentation alludes to it. You are stuck with the default autofiltering being applied to a table WHEN the workbook is saved. As in regardless of whatever changes you make in the code when you create the table and save, the autofilter will be applied always. A simple [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69203752/13664137) provided by @Y. I does work